# Purely functional stack implementation with scheme

Tags: functional-programming, stack, scheme, purely-functional

I would like to implement a functional stack in scheme.
This is my attempt:

```lisp
(define make-stack
  (letrec ((do-op
            (lambda (stack op . val)
              (cond ((eq? op 'push)
                     (lambda (op . v)
                       (do-op (cons (car val) stack) op v)))
                    ((eq? op 'pop)
                     (lambda (op . v)
                       (do-op (cdr stack) op v)))
                    ((eq? op 'print)
                     (begin (display stack)
                            (newline)
                            (lambda (op . v)
                              (do-op stack op v))))))))
    (lambda (op . val)
      (do-op '() op val))))
```

The stack can be used as in this example:

```lisp
(define s make-stack)
((((((s 'push 1) 'push 2) 'push 3) 'print) 'pop) 'print)
```

The output of this example is:

```
((3) (2) (1))
((2) (1))
```

Not exactly what I wanted, but not too bad.
I wanted to ask the experienced schemers here if there is a way to make the stack behave more naturally, for example like this:

```
(define s make-stack)
(s 'push 1)
(s 'push 2)
(s 'pop)
...
```

while keeping it functional (so no mutability, no `set!`).

The first thing I thought was to keep returning a function with no arguments, but changing every `lambda (op . v)` with:

```lisp
(lambda ()
  (lambda (op . v)
    ...
```

but this does not work as we still need to capture the returned function:

```lisp
> (define s make-stack)
> ((s) 'push 1)
#<procedure>
```

Comment: Your desired syntax looks like it needs a mutable stack...

Comment: @Shawn I was expecting that a more experienced schemer would come up with a macro so that my desired syntax would be realised by calling the stack and then redefining it by capturing its output. I agree this would not feel very pure.

Comment: `cons`, `car` and `cdr` are the equivalent of `push`, `peek`, and `delete` :-o
`pop` is `peek` + `delete`, but in a functional stack that is not possible,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goals are contradictory. If `s` is a stack, and your operations purely functional, then `(s 'push 1)` must return the same thing every time it is called. To capture the notion of change, you must use a different `s` each time. That's how your functional stack works: it gives you back a new stack, and you must compose function calls with it.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Your answer made me realise that at least I can re-write the `'print` part so that it does not return a new function, since printing something on the console does not change the stack.

Answer (score 2):

As Amalloy suggests, functional style has principles that contrast with your goal. It's not impossible to do something *similar*, however -

```scm
(define (run-stack s prgm)
  (foldl (lambda (step s) (apply s step))
         s
         prgm))

(run-stack
  make-stack
 '((push 1)
   (push 2)
   (push 3)
   (print)
   (pop)
   (print)))
```

To test this, I implemented `make-stack` as -

```scm
(define (dispatch-stack s)
  (lambda payload
    (match payload
      ((list 'pop)
       (dispatch-stack (cdr s)))
      ((list 'push v)
       (dispatch-stack (cons v s)))
      ((list 'print)
       (println (reverse s))
       (dispatch-stack s))
      (_ (error "invalid stack operation" payload)))))

(define make-stack
  (dispatch-stack null))
```

Output -

```
'(1 2 3)
'(1 2)
```

Another thing I think you would like to see is [*Make a language in one hour: stacker*](https://beautifulracket.com/stacker/). This will help you to see how languages like Racket are fundamentally different from others you have probably worked with before.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have `lambda payload` instead of `lambda (payload)` or is it just a typo?

Comment: J.D., it is intentional. it's a valid program you can run to verify the results. By writing `(lambda payload <expr>)`, all of the arguments passed to the lambda are collected in `payload` and allows `<expr>` to work with them as a list. A function with a varying number of parameters is known as a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity). The [define](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html) form is flexible and allows for expressing positional, curried, keyword-style, rest-style parameters, and more.

Comment: @J.D. with `lambda (payload)`, you'd have to define `run-stack` to `foldl` with `(lambda (step s) (s step))` instead, and it'd be the same overall.

Comment: I like very much this solution, it's an excellent illustration that sometimes `foldl` and `foldr` are not interchangeable.